# Using Objective-C, is there a way to convert a tree into Fast Enumeration?

Tags: objective-c, ios, fast-enumeration

If there is a tree, which has a `rootNode`, and it points to left and right for its children nodes (a binary tree), is there a way to convert it into Fast Enumeration as in Objective-C 2.0?  So we can do

```
for (id node in [tree allNodes]) {
    // do something
}
```

preferably, without constructing a O(n) object for memory size, using a collection object such as `NSMutableArray`, `NSSet`, or `NSDictionary`.

The order is not important, but it might come out as depth-first order.

Comment: This should be absolutely possible if you have your tree class conform to [NSFastEnumeration](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSFastEnumeration_protocol/Reference/NSFastEnumeration.html). What have you tried so far?

Comment: The above response is correct.  I'd look into Apple's Documentation and make your tree conform to NSFastEnumeration, as mentioned.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSFastEnumeration_protocol/Reference/NSFastEnumeration.html

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/4872564/944634

Comment: I don't know Fast Enumeration that much yet.  Right now I am looking into finding a node in a tree and need to return the node with the minimum value, and also need to return a 1 for left branch, or a 2 for right branch, for some related info... so I thought if using tree traversal (recursion), it can be kind of messy (might need a global variable or a mutable array to keep the states) (it is: for a tree of nodeViews, find the nodeView that is closest to a point on screen, and need to tell whether it is the left child or right child "connection point" of the viewNode is closest to that point)

Answer (score 2):

When you implement fast enumeration, you do not have to return all the elements at once.  Of course, all you get if you return them one at a time is fast enumeration syntax, without much of the performance benefit.

You could return a single element each time `countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count` is called, or you could return all the elements, or even just N elements.

For example, lets say you have a huge tree.  You could use the stack buffer passed to you, and its length:

```
NSUInteger numItemsToReturn = MIN(100, lengthOfStackBuffer);
```

Then, you could continue your tree traversal up to `numItemsToReturn` or until you reached the end of your tree.

The internal infrastructure will keep calling  `countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count` until it has "seen" the right number of elements.

Note, however, that if you only return part of the data, you will have to store information in the `state` so you know where to resume the next time.  That's what `extra` is for.

**EDIT**

Saw your comment on the original post...  If you want to support fast-enumeration, then it's pretty easy, as mentioned above.

However, if you just want to traverse the tree to do stuff, you may want to consider an enumeration API.  For example:

```
-(void)enumerateWithOptions:(MyTreeEnumerationOptions)options
                 usingBlock:^(id object, unsigned int level, BOOL isLeaf, BOOL *stop)block {
    // In here, you can use the options to determine if you are doing
    // pre/post depth first search, breadth-first, reverse, even concurrent.
    // You also provide an easy way to communicate to the caller not only the
    // object at this node, but the tree-depth of this node, whether it is a
    // leaf, and anything else you want to communicate.
}
```

Users could then call:

```
[tree enumerateWithOptions:PreOrderDepthFirst
                usingBlock:^(id object, unsigned int level, BOOL isLeaf, BOOL *stop) {
    // Execute whatever code you want with this object...
    // Set *stop = YES to abort the enumeration.
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

As Jody and waldrumpus say, you should conform to `NSFastEnumeration`. This would allow you to write:

```
for (id node in tree) {
    // do something
}
```

In addition to this, there are as you say a number of ways to enumerate i.e. traverse your tree: Depth first (preorder, inorder, postorder) or breadth first come to mind. You could subclass your tree and offer different implementations of the delegate method `countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count` as fits, or (better) have a typedef and property that describes how the tree is to be traversed and appeal to this in the delegate method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to traverse the tree in multiple ways (pre-, in-, post-order), you might also consider creating your own [`NSEnumerator`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSEnumerator_Class/Reference/Reference.html) subclasses instead of just conforming to `NSFastEnumeration`.

So create the NSPreorderEnumerator, NSInorderEnumerator, and NSPostOrderEnumerator subclasses which know how to traverse the tree.

Then have your tree objects respond to `-preorderEnumerator`, `-inorderEnumerator`, `-postorderEnumerator` by returning a new enumerator created for your tree.

You can then do

```
for(id node in [tree preorderEnumerator]) {
    // do stuff
}

for(id node in [tree postorderEnumerator]) {
    // do stuff
}
```

`NSArray` does something similar with `-reverseObjectEnumerator`, which allows you to loop in reverse.